# Gerar script sql em uma determinada data

Tags: sql, query, sql-server-2012

Boa tarde!

Galera, to com uma grande missão que é o seguinte. Tenho um script que eu montei abaixo que preciso que ela seja executada somente no dia 01 de cada mes respeitando as duas condições que coloquei na clausula IF. Tentei via trigger e job, porém, sem sucesso. Qual a melhor forma?

```
DECLARE @Tarefa int
SET @Tarefa = (SELECT Tarid from Tarefa)

BEGIN
IF (SELECT TarStatus FROM Tarefa WHERE TarID = @Tarefa) = 9 --ESSE 9 SIGINIFCA QUANDO O STATUS DA TAREFA TIVER CONCLUIDA
 and 
(SELECT TarTipID FROM Tarefa WHERE TarID = @Tarefa) IN (select EstTarTipID from EstoqueTarefa where EstoqueID = 47) -- ESSA CONDICAO SIGNIFICA NAQUELE DETERMINADO CAMINHO
  BEGIN 
   UPDATE EstoqueTarefa --ESSE UPDATE É PARA CHAMAR NESSA TABELA A INSERÇÃO DE NOVOS REGISTROS
   SET Ativo = 1 --1 SIGNIFICA PARA ATIVAR A TABELA PARA GERAÇÃO DAS NOVAS TAREFAS
   WHERE EstTarID = 570
  END  
END; 
  /*Produção Assistida Estratégico*/ 
  SELECT T.TarID,
       'DP-CustomerSu-47-970'  
FROM Tarefa T  
WHERE T.TarID = @Tarefa  
  AND T.TarStatus = 9
```

Comment: Sobre “_preciso que ela seja executada somente no dia 01 de cada mes_”, agende o job para ser executado no primeiro dia de cada mês. Em "Job Schedule Properties" defina Day 1 of every 1 month.

Comment: Certo, mas @JoséDiz, precisa informar nesse script que é alguma trigger por exemplo que esta só sera habilitada no dia 1 ou dessa forma mesmo a job irá entender?

Comment: Não pode (e, salvo engano de minha parte, nem é possível) ser procedimento de gatilho (_trigger_). Monte um job.